# SFML C++ Dodge Game Unresponsive

Tags: c++, 2d, sfml

I am trying to create a simple SFML game where you control a car and you have to dodge objects that are falling down from the top of the screen. When I run my program it becomes unresponsive but when I close it there are no error messages on the screen.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Paddle.h"
#include "Obstacle.h"
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
RenderWindow gameDisplay(VideoMode(1336, 900), "Dodge");

bool GameOn = true;

Texture player;
if (!player.loadFromFile("SFML_game_car.png"))
{

}

Sprite playercar;
playercar.setTexture(player);
playercar.setPosition(200,700);
playercar.setRotation(270);

Texture obstacle1;
if (!obstacle1.loadFromFile("obstacle.jpg"))
{
    //error
}

Sprite firstwall;
firstwall.setTexture(obstacle1);


Obstacle1 obstacle1object;
obstacle1object.obstacle1_spawn(firstwall, GameOn, gameDisplay);



while (gameDisplay.isOpen())
{
    Event evnt;
    while (gameDisplay.pollEvent(evnt))
    {
        switch (evnt.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            gameDisplay.close();
        case Event::KeyPressed:
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
                gameDisplay.close();

        }
    }


    while (GameOn == true)
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
        {
            Paddle paddlerightobject;
            paddlerightobject.paddle_move_right(playercar);
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
        {
            Paddle paddleleftobject;
            paddleleftobject.paddle_move_left(playercar);
        }



        gameDisplay.clear();
        gameDisplay.draw(playercar);
        gameDisplay.draw(firstwall);
        gameDisplay.display();

    }


}

return 0;
 }
```

Paddle.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

#pragma once

class Paddle
   {
    public:
   void paddle_move_right(Sprite &playercar)
{
    if (playercar.getPosition().x < 1150)
        playercar.move(0.3f, 0.0f);
}

void paddle_move_left(Sprite &playercar)
{
    if (playercar.getPosition().x > 100)
        playercar.move(-0.3f, 0.0f);
  }
};
```

Obstacle.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
int RandPosx;
#pragma once

class Obstacle1
{
 public:
void obstacle1_spawn(Sprite &firstwall, bool &GameOn, RenderWindow &gameDisplay)
{
    srand(time(0));
    RandPosx = (rand() % 300)+ 1;
    cout << RandPosx << endl;
    cout << firstwall.getPosition().y << endl;
    firstwall.setPosition(300, 100);

    while (firstwall.getPosition().y < 1000)
    {
        firstwall.move(0.0f, 0.5f);
        if (firstwall.getPosition().y > 1000)
        {
            GameOn = false;
            gameDisplay.close();
        }
    }



  }
};
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code using a debugger? At a very naive first glance it looks like `while (GameOn == true)` is never true, but I suspect you'd easily find the problem stepping over the code until you reach you hang.

Answer (score 0):

the application will never enter `while (gameDisplay.pollEvent(evnt)`, since this will be skipped when game starts, and since there is nothing inside `while (GameOn == true)` that sets `GameOn` to `false`, the application is effectively stuck inside this loop. Thus, no events can be polled, causing the unresponsiveness.

Comment: @JosephH I do recommend that you try what stepping through your program in debug mode like George suggested in his comment!